# If two bodies move opposite to each other when brought in contact, what is the direction of force of friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, friction

We know that when a body is at rest and other is dragged over it then a force is produced which opposes the motion and consequently its direction is negative to the force applied on body to produce acceleration. But if the case handles two moving bodies such that their surfaces are in contact then what will be the direction of friction there? It must not be one-sided because the directions of motion of both bodies are opposite to each other when both moving with constant acceleration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

we often confuse or loosely say that friction opposes motion but it should be kept in mind that it opposes the "relative motion" so if two bodies are moving opposite to each other then we need to change the frame of reference from earth to the body and check what is the direction of relative velocity. once determined we can clearly say that the direction of friction will be opposite to that.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to treat two forces separately relative to each body as $\vec{F}_1=-\vec{F}_2$ and $\lvert|\vec{F}_1\rvert|=\lvert|\vec{F}_2\rvert|$. Having in mind that $\vec{F}_1(t),\vec{F}_2(t)$ both are functions of time because the motion goes with constant acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

This is the original figure,

[image]

Let's see, Here is a little modified figure. I have assumed the mass of block $A$ to be $M$, and mass of block $B$ to be $m$. As you can see the Normal forces $N$, are $mg$ and $(M+m)g$ respectively.

[image]

Now, let's draw the FBD (Free body diagram) ignoring the Normal forces, (Here we are concerned only about friction). Please note that friction is $f=\mu N$, where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction.

[image]

Hope this helps,